# Variable is null at super call

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, superclass, super

I'm using Java 7 and got 3 classes:

TestSuper.java

```
public abstract class TestSuper {
    public TestSuper() {
            testMethod();
    }

    protected abstract void testMethod();
}
```

TestNull.java

```
public class TestNull extends TestSuper {
    private String test = "Test";

    public TestNull() {
            super();
            System.out.println(test);
    }

    @Override
    protected void testMethod() {
            System.out.println(test);
    }

}
```

TestMain.java

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new TestNull();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
null
Test
```

Why does this happen and is there a good workaround for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `new TestNull();` you're calling the constructor of the class `TestNull`, which it calls the `super()` constructor: it contains a call to the method implemented in `TestNull`, where you print the String field, at this time the fields of the sub-class `TestNull` are not yet initialized, i.e. are null.

After the super constructor call, all the fields will be initialized, and therefore the second print actually show the new value of the (initialized) string.

The key point here is that fields of a sub-class are initialized **after** the instantiation of the super-classes.

A workaround? It depends on what exact behaviour you desire: maybe it makes sense to NOT call the abstract method in the super constructor (i.e. in the constructor of the `TestSuper` class).

Answer (score 2):

According to [JLS 8.1.1.1 Abstract Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1)

> A subclass of an abstract class that is not itself abstract may be
>   instantiated, *resulting in the execution of a constructor for the
>   abstract class* and, **Therefore**, *the execution of the* **Field Initializers**
>   *for instance variables of that class.*

Answer (score 1):

You are calling an **overridable** instance method (which also calls an instance field, in your case `private String test = "Test";`) in the constructor. This might cause inconsistencies since the instance is not fully constructed. This is a bad practice, so avoid it:

```
public TestSuper() {
       testMethod();
}
```

Please read this thread: [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/544983)

Answer (score 0):

you can work around this issue by moving the call of `testMethod()` to a separate function

```java
public abstract class TestSuper {
    public TestSuper() { }

    public void callTestMethod(){
      testMethod();
    }

    protected abstract void testMethod();
}
```

then call `callTestMethod()` on `TestNull` constructor

```java
public TestNull() {
      super.callTestMethod();
      System.out.println(test);
}
```